# Complementary language of $L\notin RE,coRE$

Tags: turing-machines, computability, regular-languages

I mean if $L'$ defined as $L'=\overline{L}$, when $L\notin RE,coRE$.

From the logic point of view it should be $L'\in RE \cup coRE$, isn't?

But it's not make sense for me, where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are complementing is the language, not $RE$ or $co-RE$.

$RE$ and $co-RE$ are ***families*** of languages. Complementing a language is *not the same* as complementing the *family* its in.

For instance, if we have a family of sets: $\mathcal{F}:=\{\{1,2\},\{3,4,5\},\{1,5\}\}$, when the "world" we live in only has $5$ elements: $W:=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, then taking the complement of $\{1,2\}\in \mathcal{F}$ yields $\{1,2\}'=W\setminus\{1,2\}=\{3,4,5\}\in \mathcal{F}$. But also, taking the complement of $\{1,5\}\in \mathcal{F}$ will yield $\{2,3,4\}\notin \mathcal{F}$.

As you can see, complementing a language won't guarantee you anything when talking about the same family of languages. But in the particular case of $RE$ and $co-RE$, by the definition of $co-RE$, we have that if $L\in RE$ then $L'\in co-RE$ and if $L\in co-RE$ then $L'\in RE$. Notice, that $co-RE$ is **not** the complement of $RE$! It is the family of complements of languages, and as we said it is not correlated to the complement of $RE$ directly.

Comment: Thank you, just to make sure that I understood correctly, $L'\notin RE, coRE$, is it right?